# Azure Batch Account quota

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I want to increase the quota of creating a batch account in same region.
For eg. I have the limit of creating 3 batch accounts in Central US region. However I want to create 2 more batch accounts in same region.

Is there any extra cost associated for increasing the quota?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [`Azure Subscription Limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#batch-limits), you can have a maximum of 50 batch accounts. For increasing the quota, you will need to contact Azure Support.

Regarding any extra cost, I don't think so. Based on the [`pricing`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/batch/) page, you are not charged for the account per se. Rather you're charged for the compute and other resources you deploy in these accounts to run your batch jobs.

> There is no charge for Batch itself, only the underlying compute and
>   other resources consumed to run your batch jobs. For compute, Cloud
>   Services, Linux Virtual Machines or Windows Virtual Machines can be
>   utilised by Batch.